# How should I configure my zlib DEFLATE in order to conform to Websocket permesasge-deflate standards?

Tags: c++, websocket, zlib

Currently, I have

```
deflateInit2(strm, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, 15, 8, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY)
```

and then call deflate with:

```
deflate(&strm, Z_FINISH)
```

When I send this as payload in websocket, for some messages, the compression is correct and everything works.

However, when it doesn't work, Chrome is able to deflate the first message, then for the next message, I see "(Opcode -1)" in Websocket frames and "invalid frame header" in console.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have provided enough output space for `deflate()`. Does `deflate()` return `Z_STREAM_END`?